# Amazon RDS - multi AZ

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I want to take a multi AZ RDS db instance with Amazon. But from their FAQs or guidelines I cannot find if I can select a specific AZ for the standby DB. I understand that the secondary DB will be in the same Region. Can anyone tell me if it is possible to select the AZ of the stand by ?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: i know @jww .. thought i'd get a quick answer here. even though not related to programming, i think the answer might be useful for people in the early phase of development when deciding whether to go for a multi AZ or just handling their DB replication/fail over themselves if they want or cannot have the choice of selecting the AZ location for the stand by. I wanted to ask that to Amazon directly, but my plan does not allow me to ask questions to technical support :( will try on suggested links as well. Thanks.

Comment: Please do not cross-post the [same question](https://superuser.com/q/1279321/183147) to multiple Stack Exchange sites.  Delete the original.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you select Multi-AZ deployment for the RDS instance, Amazon will manage the Master and Slave placement within the defined VPC.

This is because, when a failure happens, AWS is able to promote the secondary instance as master to handle the requests, while other database  failovers.

Note: You are only able to select the Availability Zone if you are provisioning a single instance.